# Getting XML tag values using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml

For the following XML file, I'm trying to get all the book titles and append it to a list.

XML file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Text>
 <Library>
    <Book>
            <Title>XYZ</Title>
     </Book>
     <Book>
            <Title>ABC</Title>
     </Book>
 </Library>
</Text>
```

I'm using ElementTree to extract the tag values using this code-

```
for child in root.iter('Text'):
  t1=(child.find('Library/Book/Title').text)
  t2=(child.find('Library/Book/Title').text)
  print (t1,t2)
```

I'm unable to get the second tag value. Is it possible to get both the values in one find and append it to a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get both values in a list using findall instead of find

Updated the code so it suits the comment:

```
library = []
for text in root.findall('Library'):
    titles = [title.text for title in text.findall('Book/Title')]
    library.append(titles)
```

This will make an array per library and adds each book title to that array
Result:

```
>>>print(library)
[['XYZ','ABC'],['LMN','PQR']]
```

[here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall) is the documentation

Comment: Is it possible to create a list of list using findall option? I want to create something like `[[XYZ,ABC],[LMN,PQR]]` but at the moment all values are placed in a 1D list as `[XYZ,ABC,LMN,PQR]`.

Comment: The data per Text block?

Comment: Data per Library block.

Comment: Edited the code for you so it matches how you want it.